# rails page cache expiration on multiple app servers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

How do we expire the rails page cache on multiple app servers running behind a load balancer?
I tried implementing a cache sweeper, but its only sweeping the cache on the app server which receives the request. The cached pages are stored in the public directory.

Answer (score 0):

You could either notify all servers to sweep the cache (for example via a special URL or the database, in which case you need a job which checks the db on a regular basis and invalidate the cache) or you invalidate the cache on a regular basis via a cronjob (suggest you use [whenever](http://rubygems.org/gems/whenever)).

Edit: Another solution would be to share the public directory across all machines via NFS or something like that. That way, every server can invalidate the cache for all machines.

Answer (score 0):

With the assumption that you're able to have your app servers access a common file store, you could change the location in which rails stores the cache. That way, when you expire the cache it will be reflected across all app servers. In your config simply add:

`config.cache_store = :file_store, "/path/to/cache/directory"`

That's probably the easiest way. There are other methods as well such as a memcached server.

More info here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#activesupport-cache-filestore